# Twilio is not sending creds in headers when specifying username:password format in the URL

Tags: node.js, authentication, twilio, basic-authentication, digest

I'm currently developing my app and I'm at the stage where I can start testing messages from Twilio. I configured my server on digital ocean with a public facing IP address and my Nodejs app is listening to calls from Twilio.
I also configured my phone number's message "request url" to "http://username:password@198.xxx.xxx.xxx/messages" with "HTTP POST".

When I debug the headers, I don't see the "authorization" headers. I'm I missing something here?
Any help is much appreciated!
Below is the code.

```html
var headerValues = bag.req.headers.authorization.split(' ');

  console.log(bag.req.headers);

  var scheme = headerValues[0];
  if (scheme === 'Basic') {
    var credentials = headerValues[1];
    var decoded = new Buffer(credentials, 'base64').toString().split(':');
    bag.req.creds = {
      userName: decoded[0],
      password: decoded[1],
      authType: 'basic'
    }
  }
```

Comment: What happens when you request that URL on your browser?

Comment: I don't see the headers when I use the browser either. I've used both firefox and chrome. The code is as follows (nodejs) 

if (!bag.req.headers.authorization) console.log('Headers not found!!!');

Comment: { host: '198.XXX.XXX.XXX',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/47.0.2526.106 Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
  'if-none-match': 'W/"5a-2753714540"' }

Comment: Also, I see the headers when I set the URL as a webhook on github. So, I believe something going on twilio side.

Comment: If you can't see the headers when you browse it, likely Twilio also won't be able to see it. How about you update your question with your code so i can try it out?

Comment: @MarcosPlacona: I have updated the question with my code snippet. What I don't understand is that when i use the same url as a webhook on github, I'm able to see the authorization headers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the same setup as you do in several call centers I have built.

If you are using a proxy setup which requires username:password@ before the IP address then your issue is likely with that proxy if you can access the code by going directly to the actual server ip address as I note below. However, you did not mention using a proxy just using a digital ocean droplet so I am responding assuming you do not have a proxy setup.

So if you do have a proxy setup make sure you can access the IP address of the server directly first.

Also if those are just extra variables you need to pass over you may be better off appending them after the IP address

for instance xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/username/password

Then get them with req.params

for instance (and yes this will work with post data since its merely part of the URL and not an actual get command post)

```
router.post('/sms/:username/:password'), function(req, res, next){
    username = req.params.username;
}
```

First you would not want to direct your request URL at "http://username:password@198.xxx.xxx.xxx/messages" with "HTTP POST".

If you do not have a domain directed at your IP address yet you want your request URL to be

https://198.xxx.xxx.xxx/inbound/sms

{Replacing /inbound/sms with whatever route you are using}

Then at the top of your route (I am using express so my setup may look different than your)

I have the node.js twilio library

```
  , twilio = require('twilio')
  , capability = new twilio.Capability(sid, auth)
  , client = require('twilio')(sid, auth)
```

Then here is an example of my /sms route

```
router.post('/sms', function(req, res, next){
  var sid = req.body.SmsSid;
  var from = req.body.From;
  var to = req.body.To;
  var date = Date();
   var body = req.body.Body;
  if(req.body.NumMedia > 0){
    code to handle MMS
  }

    Code to handle SMS data
   res.send("Completed");
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My api endpoint /messages can receive messages from multiple callers, with Twilio being one type of caller. Hence I'm expecting userName and password in the headers and not as URL params. I want to have one standard interface for authentication. Depending upon the caller, I transform the message to an internal format. What I have noticed is that when I provide http://username:password@198.xxx.xxx.xxx/messages as a webhook on Github, I can see the headers. So, I'm not sure why Twilio is not setting the headers?

Comment: That makes sense. I take it you have been able to confirm that when you visit from elsewhere the headers are being sent? If so then you may need to contact twilio support. It is possible they do not support the headers being send like that, though I cannot imagine why. I know I personally tried to send headers like you were and was unable to get node.js to recognize them at all. So where the problem exists will all depend on if it is working with other systems

Comment: I was able to confirm that github was setting the auth headers when invoking a webhook. My code was getting the required info from the headers. I have opened a support issue with Twilio and I'm not getting any traction there.

Comment: I will do some testing on my end and get back with you.

Comment: Thank you! Please make sure that the url is not https, just "http"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this this week and discovered that behavior surrounding Basic Auth in the URL is very cloudy. For one thing, it appears to be deprecated from the [URI spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) as it pertains to HTTP:

```
...
3.2.1.  User Information
...
Use of the format "user:password" in the userinfo field is deprecated.
...7.5.  Sensitive Information

URI producers should not provide a URI that contains a username or password that is intended to be secret.  URIs are frequently displayed by browsers, stored in clear text bookmarks, and logged by user agent history and intermediary applications (proxies).  A password appearing within the userinfo component is deprecated and should be considered an error (or simply ignored) except in those rare cases where the 'password' parameter is intended to be public.
...
```

Because of this, both Firefox and Chrome appear to just strip it out and ignore it. Curl, however, seems to convert it to a valid `Authorization` header.

**Whatever the case, I believe this functionality is actually the responsibility of the HTTP user agent, and it appears that Twilio's user agent is not doing its job. Thus, there is no way to make basic auth work.**

**However, it appears Twilio's preferred method of auth is to simply sign the request using your account's secret auth key, which you can then verify when handling the request. See [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/getting-started-twilio-webhooks).**

On researching the raw NodeJS `Request` and `IncomingMessage` classes, there appears to be no way to get at the full, raw URL to compensate for Twilio's non-conformity. I believe this is because the actual data of an HTTP request doesn't contain the full URL.

My understanding is that it's actually the HTTP *user agent* that's responsible for extracting and formatting the auth info from the URL. That is, a conformant HTTP user agent should parse the URL itself, using the hostname and port portion to find the right door on the right machine, the protocol portion to establish the connection with the listener, the verb combined with the URL's path portion to indicate what functionality to activate, and presumably it is then responsible for converting the auth section of the URL to an official HTTP `Authorization` header.

Absent that work by the user agent, there is no way to get the auth data into your system.

(This is my current understanding, although it may not be totally accurate. Others, feel free to comment or correct.)